# Return Array or object in Kotlin Dataclass

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I'm pretty new to `Kotlin` so here I go.

I have some `JSON` data that sometimes returns an object or it can return an array. See example:

Object:

```
"planograms": {
            "planogram": {
                "multiple-facings": 1,
                "planogram-seq": 838,
                "planogram-id": 252871,
                "planogram-desc": "Bulk Hardware - No Springs"
            }
        },
```

Array:

```
"planograms": {
            "planogram": [
                {
                    "multiple-facings": 1,
                    "planogram-seq": 112,
                    "planogram-id": 262027,
                    "planogram-desc": "Cat Food - Cat Dry"
                },
                {
                    "multiple-facings": 1,
                    "planogram-seq": 94,
                    "planogram-id": 276508,
                    "planogram-desc": "Cat Food - Cat Dry - A"
                }
            ]
        },
```

I am using `Retrofit2` for the parsing so here is the code that does that:

```
 fun getItemInfoExtended(@Body itemId: ItemData): Call<DefaultResponse>
```

`DefaultResponse` has more data that includes the object/array.

My question is how can I get to return the object or array. currently, I have a list in my data class, so when the object is returned I get an error stating the issue of not an array:

```
data class Planograms (
    val planogram: List<Planogram>?

)

data class Planogram (
    val multipleFacings: Long,
    val planogramSeq: Long,
    val planogramID: Long,
    val planogramDesc: String
)
```

Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: It's not good practice to return object and array on a same json key. It will be good if it always sent json array on `planogram` key.
Otherwise you have to manually parse using `JsonDeserializer`.

Comment: not sure if this will make a difference, but have you tried using ArrayList instead of List ?

Comment: Does an `Array<Planogram>` work?